# Do JPEGs have canonical representations?

Tags: image, jpeg, specifications, image-compression, lossy-compression

I have noticed something very odd. Python's Pillow, Firefox's `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`, and Photoshop CC all interpret a JPEG differently. What I mean by this is some pixels vary *very slightly* in color value. For example, a pixel at `183, 214` might have the color `(207, 019, 036)` according to Pillow, `(207, 018, 036)` according to Firefox's JavaScript implementation, and `(207, 018, 038)` according to Photoshop. They're small differences (only 5 pixels differed in the 512x512 image I tested), but they're there.

So what I'm wondering is, **do JPEGs have 100% canonical raster representations**? Is there an objectively "correct" raster version of every JPEG, **when you follow the specification**? Or is there leeway? Are there valid edge cases where values vary depending on rounding (or something similar)?

Comment: There is leeway in the downsampling of the chroma, in the quantisation of the contained frequencies and in the generation/selection of the Huffman tables which can be generated to match the frequencies present in the image.... and probably a bunch of other stuff over my head! So, I would say there is no canonical representation. I am wrong sometimes though ;-)